# How to use pd.melt to unpivot a dataframe where columns share a prefix?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, unpivot, melt

I'm trying to unpivot my data using `pd.melt` but no success so far. Each row is a business, and the data contains information about the business and multiple reviews. I want my data to have every review as a row.

My first 150 columns are in groups of 15, each group column name shares the same pattern `reviews/n/` for `0 < n < 9`. (`reviews/0/text`, `reviews/0/date`, ... , `reviews/9/date`).
The next 65 columns in the dataframe include more data about the business (e.g. `business_id`, `address`) that should remain as id_variables.

My current data looks like this:

| business_id | address | reviews/0/date | reviews/0/text | reviews/1/date | reviews/1/text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01 street | 1/1/1990 | "abc" | 2/2/1995 | "def" |

and my new dataframe should have every review as a row instead of every business, and look like this:

| business_id | address | review_number | review_date | review_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01 street | 0 | 1/1/1990 | "abc" |
| 12345 | 01 street | 1 | 2/2/1995 | "def" |

I tried using `pd.melt` but could not succeed in making code that produced something valuable to me.

Comment: How can regex help you here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to do what you want.

However, you will need to rename your columns from the pattern `reviews/N/COL` to `reviews/COL/N` (or something similar) first, as `wide_to_long()` can only unpivot based on prefixes, whereas in your column names, you have a prefix and a suffix.

You could do this manually or e.g. using the `re` module and an appropriate regex:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('reviews/(\d)/(.*)', r'review_\2\1', x))
```

After that, your data should look like this (note the changed colnames):

| business_id | address | review_date0 | review_text0 | review_date1 | review_text1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01 street | 1/1/1990 | abc | 2/2/1995 | def |

Now you can use `pandas.wide_to_long()` and use the `stubnames` parameter to specify the prefix of the columns that should be grouped when you unpivot.

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                     stubnames=['review_date','review_text'],
                     i=['business_id', 'address'], 
                     j='review_number')
```

Finally, call `.reset_index()` to achieve the result you asked for.

Full example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'business_id': 12345, 
                   'address': '01 street', 
                   'reviews/0/date': '1/1/1990', 
                   'reviews/0/text': 'abc', 
                   'reviews/1/date': '2/2/1995', 
                   'reviews/1/text': 'def'}, index = [0])

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('reviews/(\d)/(.*)', r'review_\2\1', x))

df = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                     stubnames=['review_date','review_text'],
                     i=['business_id', 'address'], 
                     j='review_number').reset_index()
```

Result:

| business_id | address | review_number | review_date | review_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01 street | 0 | 1/1/1990 | abc |
| 12345 | 01 street | 1 | 2/2/1995 | def |

Answer (score 2):

You can get the names of all the non-review columns.

```
columns = df.columns[~df.columns.str.match(r'reviews/\d+/')]
```

```
>>> columns
Index(['address', 'business_id'], dtype='object')
```

And use those to `.melt()`

```
df = df.melt(columns)

df['review_number'] = df['variable'].str.extract(r'reviews/(\d+)')
df['variable'] = df['variable'].str.replace(r'reviews/\d+/', 'review_')
```

```
>>> df
  address  business_id     variable                value review_number
0  street            1  review_date  1990-01-01 00:00:00             0
1  street            1  review_text                "abc"             0
2  street            1  review_date  1995-02-02 00:00:00             1
3  street            1  review_text                "def"             1
```

From there you can `.pivot()`

```
>>> df.pivot(index=columns.union(['review_number']).to_list(), columns='variable')
                                                 value            
variable                                   review_date review_text
address business_id review_number                                 
street  1           0              1990-01-01 00:00:00       "abc"
                    1              1995-02-02 00:00:00       "def"
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - in this case we use the special placeholder `.value` to identify the parts of the column that we want to remain as headers, while the rest get collated into a new column :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['business_id', 'address'], 
    names_to = ['.value', 'reviewnumber', '.value'], 
    names_pattern = r"(review)s/(\d+)/(.+)"
 )
.rename(columns = lambda f: f.replace('review', 'review_'))
) 
   business_id    address review_number review_date review_text
0        12345  01 street             0    1/1/1990         abc
1        12345  01 street             1    2/2/1995         def
```

A regex gives the flexibility to extract the labels into separate columns. Note that you can use `.value` as many times as you want, as long as you get the regex right.

Another option is with `pd.stack`, where the columns are split before transforming - as much as possible generally, if you can, split the columns before flipping, not after ( the larger the data size the more performant this option is ):

```py
temp = df.set_index(['business_id', 'address'])
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split("/", expand=True)
temp.columns.names = [None, 'review_numbers', None]
# quick route - the collapse_levels function 
# is from pyjanitor
# temp.stack('review_numbers').collapse_levels().reset_index()
temp = temp.stack('review_numbers')
temp.columns = temp.columns.map("_".join)
temp.reset_index()
   business_id    address review_numbers reviews_date reviews_text
0        12345  01 street              0     1/1/1990          abc
1        12345  01 street              1     2/2/1995          def
```